# How to change an entire tables text color with prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

I have a RoR app that generates a pdf page using the prawn gem:

```
class ReportPdf < Prawn::Document
 def initialize(employees)
  super(top_margin: 70)
  @employees = employees
  list_employees
 end

 def list_employees
  move_down 20
  table list_employee_rows do
   row(0).font_style = :bold
   columns(1..4).align = :right
   self.row_colors = ["E8EDFF", "FFFFFF"]
   self.row(0).background_color = '005C89'
   self.row(0).text_color = "FFFFFF"
   self.header = true
  end
 end

 def list_employee_rows
  [["Name", "Badge number"]] +
  @employees.map do |employee|
   [employee.name, employee.badge_number]
  end
 end
end
```

I can change a specific row's text color (above I've changed the header's color to white) but how would I set the entire tables text color (and not the already set header's color)?

Answer (score 3):

It's simple one line change in your `list_employees`.

Your `list_employees` method should look like this:

```
def list_employees
    move_down 20
    table list_employee_rows do
      row(0).font_style = :bold
      columns(1..4).align = :right
      self.cell_style = { :text_color => "ffffff"}
      self.row(0).background_color = '005C89'
      self.row(0).text_color = "FFFFFF"
      self.row_colors = ["E8EDFF", "FFFFFF"]
      self.header = true
    end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `table`s `do` block you should be able to define the properties of all the cells using a call to `cells.style`. There you will be able to define all the properties you like.